# Not able to connect to oracle database using Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to Oracle, I have installed `Oracle Server 11g2` and `Oracle SQL Developer` (client) tool.

I am able to connect server from command prompt successfully, please have a look here : http://prntscr.com/hytzdn

I am trying to connect the server from `Oracle SQL Developer` (client) tool but it's not allowing me. I am getting this **SID** specific error : http://prntscr.com/hyu1i2

Can someone please help me to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first screenshot doesn't contain the SQLPLUS connection string - that's pretty critical. Also it's much more useful for everyone if you copy/paste the error into the question so it's searchable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your command prompt connection type  this query

select * from global_name;

Then in sql developer change your sid name with the query result.